# To get the correct code of task scheduler's LastTaskResult using taskservice?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, task, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

Am displaying the scheduled tasks with the respective tasks and the `lastTaskResult` using the `taskservice`. In the `taskservice` the property of `lastTaskResult` is `int`, ie

```
// Summary:
//     Gets the results that were returned the last time the registered task was run.
//
// Remarks:
//     The value returned is the last exit code of the last program run via an Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.ExecAction.
public int LastTaskResult { get; }
```

so since its datatype is `int`, I'm not getting the exact exit codes as available in the task scheduler,, how can I get the entire `lastaction` result?